# Complex integration involving work

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I am going through a Complex Analysis text and I am trying to solve the question

> A force field is given by $F=3z+5$. Find the work done in moving an object in this force fiel dalong the parabola $z=t^2+it$ from $z=0$ to $z=4+2i$.

In the solution, the author writes

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text { Total work done } &=\int_{C} F \cdot d z=\operatorname{Re} \int_{C} \bar{F} \cdot d z=\operatorname{Re}\left\{\int_{C}(3 \bar{z}+5) d z\right\} \\
&=\operatorname{Re}\left\{3 \int_{C} \bar{z} d z+5 \int_{C} d z\right\}=\operatorname{Re}\left\{3\left(10-\frac{1}{2} i\right)+5(4+2 i)\right\}=50
\end{aligned}
$$

Why is it that $$\int_{C} F \cdot d z=\operatorname{Re} \int_{C} \bar{F} \cdot d z$$?

This step feels pulled out of nowhere to me. Thank you!

Comment: Write $F = F_x + i F_y$ and $dx = dx + i \, dy$ and break down the integral $\int F \, dz$. Presumably work is taken to be real valued. You'll see that by taking the approach they do, it is the same as $\int \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$

Comment: @CameronWilliams If work is taken to be real valued, why don't they take the real part of the original integral?

Comment: Because that won't match the usual definition. Do what I suggested. You'll see why they did what they did.